# "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

This autohotkey program will get me only part of the way.
I need to select  "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" and click properties on the "Wireless Network Connection Properties"

```
Run ncpa.cpl 
WinWaitActive Network Connections
SendInput {Tab 4}{Right}!{Enter} ; change {Tab 4} to suit the position of  your specific connection in the Connections list
WinWaitActive Wireless Network Connection Properties ; change the title if necessary, for example, if you're on LAN.
SendInput {Down 4}!r
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to change the IP address of the device?

Changing the ip and gateway:

```
Run, PowerShell New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceAlias “Wireless Network Connection” –IPv4Address “192.168.0.1” –PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 192.168.0.254
```

Changing the primary and secondary dns server:

```
Run, PowerShell Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias “Wireless Network Connection” -ServerAddresses 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2
```